# How to get difference between 2 timestamp values in SAP Hana?

Tags: hana, sql-timestamp

I have two column timestamps values and would like to find out difference between those times in SAP HANA.
I have not found any easiest way to find out like other DB. For better understanding, an example has been given in the following.

COLUMN1:                                          COLUMN2:

Thu Oct 01 2020 09:18:08 GMT+0200 (CEST)        Thu Oct 01 2020 15:49:40 GMT+0200 (CEST)

**Resulting Column**: 06 hours 31 min 32s

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xx_between functions (days_between, seconds_between, nano100_between) and then you can do some math, as in:

> CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(                                               CONCAT(to_varchar(to_integer(DAYS_BETWEEN(ED."START_TIME", ED."END_TIME")),'00'), 'D '), -- Days
> to_varchar(to_integer(NANO100_BETWEEN(Table1."START_TIME", Table1."END_TIME")/10000000/60/60)-DAYS_BETWEEN(Table1."START_TIME", Table1."END_TIME")*24,'00') --Hours),':'),
> to_varchar(to_integer(((NANO100_BETWEEN(Table1."START_TIME", Table1."END_TIME")/10000000/60/60)-to_integer(NANO100_BETWEEN(Table1."START_TIME", Table1."END_TIME")/10000000/60/60))*60),'00') --Minutes
> ),':'),to_varchar(to_integer(((((NANO100_BETWEEN(Table1."START_TIME", Table1."END_TIME")/10000000/60/60)-to_integer(NANO100_BETWEEN(Table1."START_TIME", Table1."END_TIME")/10000000/60/60))*60) -                  to_integer(((NANO100_BETWEEN(Table1."START_TIME", Table1."END_TIME")/10000000/60/60)-to_integer(NANO100_BETWEEN(Table1."START_TIME", Table1."END_TIME")/10000000/60/60))*60))*60), '00'))

The code is written in a way to understand what is going on in terms of time conversion. It could be shortend a lot, if needed.

Comment: No need to recalculate each difference every time, just get the seconds_between and then do division and subtraction with another select statement over the result